# How can I prevent hyphenation in a table column?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, hyphenation

I have a table (tabular) with some fixed width columns, and I'd like to prevent a hyphen being inserted (preferring a line break to be inserted prematurely).

The sample table's content is below.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}}
Want to avoid hyphenation & also want to avoid hyphenation here \\
\end{tabular}
```

How can I do this? I'd also like to tell latex not to allow each column to exceed its specified width (so I don't want a solution that means assigning hyphenation the same badness rating as an overfull hbox).

Comment: Setting `\hyphenpenalty10000` causes the hyphenation to go away for me and I get no overfull hboxes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Setting the text ragged right will do this for you. Something like

```
\usepackage{array}
...
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{4cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}}
Want to avoid hyphenation & also want to avoid hyphenation here \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Better use `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e`, no?

Comment: The point was to not have hyphenation. `\RaggedRight`'s whole purpose is to allow hyphenation.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately this now means that I can't use the booktabs package with \midrule and \bottomrule (in both cases I get a misplace \noalign error).

Comment: Oh, that just means I was lazy with my example. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks -- I have no idea what \arraybackslash is for but that fixes the problem.

Comment: Strangely, it's not documented in array.dtx, but it is documented in tabularx: "LATEX’s \raggedright macro redefines \\ in a way which conflicts with its use in a tabular or array environments. For this reason this package introduces the command \arraybackslash, this may be used after a \raggedright, \raggedleft or \centering declaration."

Comment: @Will: Thanks for the original answer and the extra insights on why it works.