# Soft midrule in table

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabu

**3 small questions:**

**1)** I'd like to put a soft  \midrule in this table between Care type and the headers, but I'd like it to not quite reach the edge of the table: (at your discretion to mess with the layout of table )

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepckage{Something extra}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
 \centering\makebox[\textwidth]
  {\resizebox{1.1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{*6X}
 \toprule
 \multicolumn{6}{c}{Care Type} \\
 \midrule
 \vspace{3pt}
 \textbf{Direct care} & \textbf{Housekeeping} & \textbf{Mealtimes} & \textbf{Medication rounds  } & \textbf{Miscellaneous} & \textbf{Personal care} \\
 \midrule
 Blood pressure measurement & Equipment cleaning& Dispensing meals& Distributing medication&Call requests&Toiletting\\
 & &&&&\\
 Weights & Cleaning patient surfaces& &Injections&Bed making &Changing\\
 & &&&&\\
 SATs~\footnote{Blood sugar saturation}  & &&&&\\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}}}
\smallskip
 \caption{Activity type and examples of each}
 \label{tab:activities}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[\midrule dashed and colored in booktabs -- two kinds of midrules in one booktab](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78972/midrule-dashed-and-colored-in-booktabs-two-kinds-of-midrules-in-one-booktab)

**2)** Also is there an out-of-the box to get table footnotes in, as I don't know where mine have gone?
[Footnotes tabularx-environment LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51454/footnotes-tabularx-environment-latex)

**3)** How to avoid the text in each cell being stretched to fill it and hence making odd hyphenations (eg. cleaning           pa-tient surfaces) and or (eg. Hygiene       prod-ucts)?

Comment: I would suggest making this three separate questions or showing how they are all related (or stemming from one base question, perhaps?).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2890.  As for the stretching, I haven't tested this one bit - but try putting it in a box, maybe?  (Also, what is `Something extra`? If you can't say and you're sure it isn't important, just remove it -- otherwise stick it back in there...)

Comment: just a comment on the format: the multi-line entries would look much nicer with `\raggedright` (or `\RaggedRight` using `ragged2e` if you want to retain hyphenation).

Comment: @barbarabeeton this might do the trick. Where do I put that \RaggedRight command in the table context? on ever line? Just somewhere inside the environment?

Comment: @HCAI -- david carlisle has included `\raggedright` in his answer, along with a method of getting the rule you asked for, so i think you should go with that.  (the `\raggedright` is placed in every "paragraph" cell in the table, but since all of the cells are defined the same way, this is done with code that is automatically replicated 6 times, once for each column.  it's nice clean, compact code; recommended.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `\cmidrule` but I also removed `tabularx` and the scale box commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepckage{Something extra}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
 \centering
\begin{tabular}{{}*6{>{\hspace{0pt}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-10\tabcolsep)/6\relax}}@{}}
 \toprule
 \multicolumn{6}{c}{Care Type} \\
 \cmidrule(l{2em}r{2em}){1-6}
\addlinespace[2ex]
 \textbf{Direct care} & \textbf{House\-keeping} & \textbf{Meal\-times} & \textbf{Medi\-cation rounds  } & \textbf{Misc\-ellaneous} & \textbf{Personal care} \\
 \midrule
 Blood pressure measurement & Equipment cleaning& Dispensing meals& Distributing medication&Call requests&Toiletting\\
 & &&&&\\
 Weights & Cleaning patient surfaces& &Injections&Bed making &Changing\\
 & &&&&\\
 SATs~\footnote{Blood sugar saturation}  & &&&&\\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\smallskip
 \caption{Activity type and examples of each}
 \label{tab:activities}
\end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is absolutely superb, many many thanks indeed! Incidentally the code in my question actually from this very forum where I asked how to make the table fit centrally on the page. What is the 10\tabcolsep)/6 bit? this looks insanely useful at preventing the whole kit and caboodle from flooding off the page! I wish there was a gallery where people could showcase this sort of professional looking code. Is there?

Comment: @HCAI tabcolsep is the padding latex puts either side of each column. The outer padding is suppressed with `@{}` so for 6 columns you just have the 5 inner separations of 2\tabcolsep so the width available for columns is \textwidth-10\tabcolsep so the width of each column is 1/6 of that.